# lagging with animation, handler, thread in android studio

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to make a custom menu bar with slidingPanel activity.
But there was lagging when I start animation.

I searched and figured out there is UI thread and recommended to use
thread and handler. I rewrite code but there is still lagging when I active
below function.

Is there any wrong?

```
public void animHandler(){
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    slidingPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingRel);
                    slidingPanel.startAnimation(translateLeftAnim);
                    slidingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });

        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Having it executed on a different thread but then updating it in the UI thread won't exactly fix the lagging issues, since it is still executed in the main thread.

You could either use [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) to update all of the UI on a background thread or just completely make it a custom view which properly handles the animation.